# Add values to a column from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = {'emp': [123, 234], 'state': ['AL', 'CA'], 'start_time': ['08:00', '08:00'], 'end_time': ['17:00', '17:00']
df.head()
emp|state|start_time|end_time
123|AL|11/05/2020 08:00|11/05/2020 17:00
234|CA|11/05/2020 08:00|11/05/2020 17:00
```

I also have a separate dictionary as follows:

```
START_ADJUST = {"AL": 0, "CA": 20}
```

Need a python function that for each state in df adds the number of minutes that is a value for that state key in the dictionary to the value of the military time in 'start_time in the dataframe.

Here's what I tried:

```
df['prep_mins'] = df['state'].map(START_ADJUST)
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['prep_mins'], unit = 'm')
```

Expected outcome:

```
emp|state|start_time|end_time
123|AL|11/05/2020 08:00|11/05/2020 17:00
234|CA|11/05/2020 08:20|11/05/2020 17:00
```

Outcome I'm getting:

```
emp|state|start_time|end_time
123|AL|11/05/2020 08:00|11/05/2020 17:00
234|CA|11/05/2020 08:00|11/05/2020 17:00
```

<strike>Two</strike> One question<strike>s</strike>:

1. How do you add minutes to military time?

<strike>2) How do add the value of a dictionary value to a column in a data fame?</strike>

Comment: A DataFrame is not a dictionary, although you can create a DataFrame from a dictionary. Please update your code to reflect the problem you're having. Also, what have you tried yourself? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Updated my question and solved some of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.  I added date to original data, and changed the time offset from 0 to 1, to verify that all adjustments get applied.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'emp': [123, 234], 
      'state': ['AL', 'CA'], 
      'start_time': ['2020-11-05 08:00', '2020-11-05 08:00'], 
      'end_time':   ['2020-11-05 17:00', '2020-11-05 17:00'],
     }
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)

# convert data type
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'])

# original adjustments
start_adjust = {"AL": 1, "CA": 20}

# convert data type
start_adjust = {
    key: pd.to_timedelta(value, unit='minute')
    for key, value in start_adjust.items()
}

# apply adjustment
df['start_time'] += df.apply(lambda x: start_adjust[x['state']], axis=1)

# results
print(df)

   emp state          start_time            end_time
0  123    AL 2020-11-05 08:01:00 2020-11-05 17:00:00
1  234    CA 2020-11-05 08:20:00 2020-11-05 17:00:00
```

Comment: Tried that out on my side, and that worked!  Thanks!